# How to import Motor on Micropython into a DFRobot Quad Motor Shield

Tags: python, robotics, micropython

I am attempting to import two motors onto my pyboard in micropython that are connected to my DFRobot DC Quad Motor Shield. Example code from them is written in Arduino and I cannot translate. Attached is my previous code that did not work and the motor shield over view with its speeds and connections.

Any help is appreciated!

[Code Previously Written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QQE8.png)

[Board Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fKwG.png)

Here is what I have

```py
i2c = machine.I2C(scl=machine.Pin('Y9'), sda=machine.Pin('Y10'))
motors = motor.DCMotors(i2c)
MOTOR1 = 3
MOTOR2 = 4
#Initiate Communication from Sonar sensor
sensor_front = adafruit_hcsr04.HCSR04(trigger_pin=board.Pin('X3'), echo_pin=board.Pin('X4'))
sensor_back = adafruit_hcsr04.HCSR04(trigger_pin=board.Pin('X6'), echo_pin=board.Pin('X7'))
#Create minimum distance For Ultrasonic sensor
min_distance = sensor.distance(70)
button = pyb.switch()
def autonomy():
    #no_problem = True
    while (True):
        if (button()):
            dist_front = sensor1.distance(15)
            dist_back = sensor2.distance(15)
            if dist_front > min_distance:
                print('Nothing can stop me!')
                motors.speed(MOTOR1, 1500)
                motors.speed(MOTOR2,-1500)
```

Here is the arduino code

```py
/*!
* @file QuadMotorDriverShield.ino
* @brief QuadMotorDriverShield.ino  Motor control program
*
* Every 2 seconds to control motor positive inversion
* 
* @author linfeng(490289303@qq.com)
* @version  V1.0
* @date  2016-4-5
*/
const int E1 = 3; ///<Motor1 Speed
const int E2 = 11;///<Motor2 Speed
const int E3 = 5; ///<Motor3 Speed
const int E4 = 6; ///<Motor4 Speed

const int M1 = 4; ///<Motor1 Direction
const int M2 = 12;///<Motor2 Direction
const int M3 = 8; ///<Motor3 Direction
const int M4 = 7; ///<Motor4 Direction


void M1_advance(char Speed) ///<Motor1 Advance
{
 digitalWrite(M1,LOW);
 analogWrite(E1,Speed);
}
void M2_advance(char Speed) ///<Motor2 Advance
{
 digitalWrite(M2,HIGH);
 analogWrite(E2,Speed);
}
void M3_advance(char Speed) ///<Motor3 Advance
{
 digitalWrite(M3,LOW);
 analogWrite(E3,Speed);
}
void M4_advance(char Speed) ///<Motor4 Advance
{
 digitalWrite(M4,HIGH);
 analogWrite(E4,Speed);
}

void M1_back(char Speed) ///<Motor1 Back off
{
 digitalWrite(M1,HIGH);
 analogWrite(E1,Speed);
}
void M2_back(char Speed) ///<Motor2 Back off
{
 digitalWrite(M2,LOW);
 analogWrite(E2,Speed);
}
void M3_back(char Speed) ///<Motor3 Back off
{
 digitalWrite(M3,HIGH);
 analogWrite(E3,Speed);
}
void M4_back(char Speed) ///<Motor4 Back off
{
 digitalWrite(M4,LOW);
 analogWrite(E4,Speed);
}



void setup() {
  for(int i=3;i<9;i++)
    pinMode(i,OUTPUT);
  for(int i=11;i<13;i++)
    pinMode(i,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
M1_advance(100);
M2_advance(100);
M3_advance(100);
M4_advance(100);
delay(2000); ///<Delay 2S
M1_back(100);
M2_back(100);
M3_back(100);
M4_back(100);
delay(2000); ///<Delay 2S
}
```

Comment: Can you post the arduino code? If you get closed. Repost on https://forum.micropython.org/index.php

Comment: Can you repost your code. It has to all be indented an extra 4 spaces for the stackoverflow to make it into a code block

Comment: @rhubarbdog There, sorry for such a late response.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Kyle Everett Shapen i looked at the arduino code.  The device is not i2c it works by `.write_digital()` to a pin to engage that motor followed by `.write_analog()` to another pin to control  the speed. Do you have a pdf for this device? Post a link to it. I think i know how to wire it up and get mooving.

Comment: This is link to the product page and that’s all the documentation I have on it. https://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/Quad_Motor_Driver_Shield_for_Arduino_SKU:DRI0039

Comment: Also, thank you for the help. That makes a little more sense. Was only taught to use an i2c so it’s confusing for me.

Comment: How does it connect to an arduino uno? Do you just use jumper cables between the arduino and motor hat's digital (green) bus or does it push straight on like a raspberry pi HAT

Comment: Does it have pins on the bottom to plug onto an arduino uno

Comment: Which pyboard are you using. It effects the program I'm going to supply

Comment: The MicroPython pyboard v1.1. Linked here ---> https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14413

Comment: I am not connecting to arduino Uno I'm going straight from my micropython Pyboard to the motor shield

Comment: Wow thank you for the detail. I think this will finally get me moving thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's attempt one. Consider using fuses until we're certain this is how to connect a DFRobot Motor HAT to a pyboard.
The connection point on the motor hat is the green digital bus.

```
import pyb                                                                  

# don't use timers 2,3,5,6                                                  

'''                                                                         
connect:                                                                    
pyboard   Motor Hat                                                         
  X1         4                                                              
  X3         3          
 GND        GND                                            
'''                                                                         

FREQ = 50                                                                   

backward = pyb.Pin('X1' ,pyb.Pin.OUT_PP)                                    
speed = pyb.Timer(9, freq=FREQ).channel(1, pyb.Timer.PWM,\
                  pin = pyb.Pin('X3'))                                                                             

while True:                                                                 
    backward.high()                                                         
    for percent in range(100):                                                 
        speed.pulse_width_percent(percent + 1)
        pyb.delay(10)
    speed.pulse_width_percent(0)

    backward.low()
    for percent in range(100):
        speed.pulse_width_percent(percent + 1)
        pyb.delay(10)
    speed.pulse_width_percent(0)
```

I've guessed FREQ to be 50Hz it's that for many servos and i'm guessing arduino uses this as a default value for PWM (pulse width modulation).

Connect a motor to connector M1 and a battery to the motor hat's power socket. Don't connect to v+ on the pyboard. Power your pyboard with it's own power source. You motor hat probably creates a lot of electrical noise.

The motor should go backwards speeding up then suddenly stopping before going forwards getting faster then suddenly stop.

good luck

Comment: @Kyle Everett Shapen i noticed you were also using an HCSR04 ultrasonic distance measurement. Here's a link to some pyboard code for this https://github.com/rhubarbdog/pyboard-hcsr04.